# Java .jar without specific letters(polish letters)

Tags: java, file, jar

I made a small program which reads txt files  and display them in JavaFx  TextArea. When I test program in IDE(Intellij) everything works fine, all the letters are displayed well. But when i build artifact and run .jar the text isnt displayed correctly(doesnt have polish signs).
Anyone can help?

Comment: Most likely a character encoding issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the JRE used to run your code inside the IDE have **different encoding settings** from the one you use to run the JAR.

Try to setup the correct enconding when you run the JAR:

```
java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -jar yourapp.jar
```

Check for the supported encoding here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html